# touchpad not working on acer es1-111M-c1le PLEASE help

Tags: drivers, touchpad, synaptics

i installed ubuntu 14.04and the touchpad stopped working.
I tried psmouse-alps-dkms_0.10_all it says command not found.

i tried sudo modprobe -r psmouse && sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps
and got:

```
Virtual core pointer                        id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech M510                             id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HD WebCam                                 id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Acer WMI hotkeys                          id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

i tried 3.17-rc6
it says command not found

i tried synclient | grep TapButton
Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?

What do i do? PLEASE;PLEASE;PLEASE help needed :)

Comment: First of all try to upgrade the kernel. Run `sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-wily` and reboot. If the touchpad does not work, post output of `xinput` again.

Comment: thank you, but not working

Comment: And what does `xinput` show now? And also post output of `dkms status`.

Comment: You said "stopped working" Did it work before?

Comment: with windows 8.1, the touchpad was working

Comment: It looks like the touchpad is not supported by Ubuntu kernels yet.

Comment: I installed dkms with sudo apt-get install dkms

Comment: You do not need it. I tried to check if you already installed something wrong. Please do not install anything. You can try the latest mainline kernel.

Comment: kernels already  installed

Comment: Which kernels are installed?

Comment: Aspire-ES1-111M 4.2.0-27-generic #32~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 22 15:32:26 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: You can try to install mainline 4.5.

Comment: done, now? it s still not working...

Comment: It is not done yet. I will write an answer, if it does not work, then you can just report it to launchpad.

Comment: And please make sure that the touchpad is not disabled by Fn+some Fn button.

Comment: i checked the fn f7 button

Comment: still not working..... :(

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install mainline kernel 4.5rc4

Run

```
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.5-rc4-wily/linux-headers-4.5.0-040500rc4-generic_4.5.0-040500rc4.201602141731_amd64.deb
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.5-rc4-wily/linux-headers-4.5.0-040500rc4_4.5.0-040500rc4.201602141731_all.deb
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.5-rc4-wily/linux-image-4.5.0-040500rc4-generic_4.5.0-040500rc4.201602141731_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb
```

Then reboot.

If the touchpad still does not work, report this issue to launchpad by running

```
ubuntu-bug linux
```

Comment: I fixed the 3rd command. There was an error.

Comment: still not working   ..... :(

Answer (score 0):

I found that setting bios touchpad to "basic" instead of "advanced" solved the problem (although "shutdown" did not work). The setting must be returned to "advanced" before reinstalling windows however. (Acer Aspire E17)